# Save WooCommerce Order Product Name to User Meta Custom Field

Tags: woocommerce, custom-fields

Caveat: I'm a solo freelance designer not a developer ;-)

I've created a custom field in the Wordpress user meta called `membership`.

I've tried the following code to save the WooCommerce Product Name to the `membership` custom field on checkout [with help from this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/97228/3206).

**Updated attempt**:

```
function wascc_woocommerce_checkout_update_user_meta_membership ( $customer_id, $posted ) {

    if (isset($posted['$orderid'])) {
        $order = $posted['$orderid'];
    }
    $theorder = new WC_Order( $order );
    $items = $theorder->get_items();

    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        $product_name = $item['name'];
    }

    if (!(empty($product_name))) {
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'membership', $product_name);
    }   

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_user_meta', 'wascc_woocommerce_checkout_update_user_meta_membership', 10, 2 );
```

It produces no error, but does not save the product name to `membership`.

Help appreciated.

[Last question may be related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36705713/how-to-save-woocommerce-checkout-custom-fields-to-user-meta).

Comment: Please re-read @Reigel's answer that you've accepted. The 2nd parameter is `$posted`, which contains the `$_POST[]` values and not `$order_id` that you are using in the code above. Because the code cannot find a valid order, its not saving the meta.

Comment: use `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta` from your last question... it has the order id... and you can get customer id from order id... I can't give full code right now cause I'm on mobile...

Comment: I can't see where the order_id is in `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta`.

Comment: I've updated my attempt above @Reigel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as I've commented out, you should use `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta`.

Something like this:

```
function wascc_woocommerce_checkout_update_user_meta_membership ( $order_id ) {

    $theorder = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $items = $theorder->get_items();

    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        $product_name = $item['name'];
    }

    if (!(empty($product_name))) {

        // Gets the customer/user ID associated with the order. Guests are 0.
        $customer_id = $theorder->get_user_id();

        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'membership', $product_name );

    }   

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'wascc_woocommerce_checkout_update_user_meta_membership' );
```

I have doubts with your foreach loop though... you are looping just to get the last item?

Comment: Yes! :-) Thank you Reigel. I thought the same thing about my foreach loop, but didn't investigate how to get the last item. I will do so.